# Airflow ignore for subdirectories and files

Tags: python, airflow

I have my repository as

```
    - .airflowignore
    - requirements.txt
    - scheduler.py
    - config/
    - dev/
        - engine/
            - dags/
            - src_code/
            - config/
        - common/
            - dags/
            - config/
            - res/
            - something.yaml
        - code_dir/
            - dags/
            - config/
            - code/
            - something_else.yaml
```

I have added airflowignore file in the root directory, but I want it to only check the dags directory under each directory (engine, common, code_dir)

I have tried specifying all the respective directories to be ignored like:

```
dev/engine/src_code/
dev/engine/config/

dev/common/config/
dev/common/res/
dev/common/something.yaml

dev/code_dir/config/
dev/code_dir/code/
dev/code_dir/something_else.yaml
```

This isn't the best method, I tried using negation to specify like:

```
# ignore all files/sub-dirs from root dir
*

# whitelist engine dir dags
!/dev/engine/dags

# whitelist common dir dags
!/dev/common/dags

# whitelist code_dir dir dags
!/dev/code_dir/dags
```

But this also didn't work.
Do provide an optimal solution.
PS. I also want to ignore all the files in the dev dir also.